# Table alignment in Google AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to set a view on a page so that user don't need to scroll down the page to see the table data list and I did it as on the picture. The page won't scroll down even the amount of data exceed what a page can hold. Hence, the table list provides a scrolling on the right of the table (circled in red) .. yet the problem is with the table alignment. As you can see the table column doesn't align with their respective data anymore due to the presence of the scrolling bar.

[image]

Below is the page view when I zoomed out the page and as you can see when there is no scroll bar on the right .. the table alignment work just fine between the column and their data.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to adjust the alignment so that in any case the column with their data will always align? Or if there is a way that Google AppMaker can freeze the table column header will be great too. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are you using but in my case, I usually set the Table Panel style in Style Editor like:

```
overflow-y: hidden !important;
```

Then the scrollbar will disappear. Hope this help.

Comment: That worked for me, however after doing it, I was not able to scroll up or down. If the scroll bar is hidden the panel is stucked and cannot go up or down. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just figured out. you have to use .element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }  where element is the name of the panel you want the scroll to be hidden